# How to draw an ellipse at random points within a set range?

Tags: c#

I am a student learning C# at school and have a project due in our Graphics Unit. I have created a Christmas tree using points and filled it in. Now I'm looking to created ellipse ornaments within the range I have already declared in the tree. Is there a way to make these ellipses only within my tree, and to have them change based on a random number generator within the tree? Thank you.

Here is my code for the tree. The ellipses I made are for snowflakes.
SolidBrush green = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);

```
    Pen greentree = new Pen(Color.Green);

    Point[] christmastree = new Point[11];
    christmastree[0] = new Point(518, 400);
    christmastree[1] = new Point(620, 300);
    christmastree[2] = new Point(549, 300);
    christmastree[3] = new Point(645, 185);
    christmastree[4] = new Point(607, 185);
    christmastree[5] = new Point(673, 102);
    christmastree[6] = new Point(744, 185);
    christmastree[7] = new Point(706, 185);
    christmastree[8] = new Point(793, 300);
    christmastree[9] = new Point(720, 300);
    christmastree[10] = new Point(835, 400);
    g.DrawPolygon(greentree, christmastree);
    g.FillPolygon(green, christmastree);

    //Snow
    Random r = new Random();
    SolidBrush snowsb = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
    for(int i = 1; i <= 40; i++)
    {
        int snowflake_x = r.Next(1000);
        int snowflake_y = r.Next(500);
        g.FillEllipse(snowsb, snowflake_x, snowflake_y, 4,4);
    }
```

Like I said, I very inexperienced in this area of C#. Thank you

Comment: You should post some code of your tree and/or what you've done for ellipses. Yes, it is possible, but we need to better understand what we're working with to help you.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly! If you have a polygon list of points you can use a graphicspath made from it and test GP.IsVisible(Point) to see if the center of your ellipse is in the tree area..

Comment: Just posted my code. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
Random r = new Random();

// Number of ellipses
int ellipseCount = 0;

// Loop for setting a specified amount of ellipses
while (ellipseCount < 10)
{

    // New random point 
    Point p = new Point(r.Next(0, 300), r.Next(0,300));
    // check if point is in my range
    if (p.IsInMyRange())
    {
         Ellipse e = new Ellipse {Width = 10, Height = 10};
         // Implement: set coordinates to ellipse

         ellipseCount++;
    }
}
```

you need to implement a method which tests if your point is in your range. With no code of you I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
namespace Baum
{
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            PointF[] tree = new PointF[]
            {
                new PointF(12, 0),
                new PointF(16, 4),
                new PointF(13, 4),
                new PointF(19, 11),
                new PointF(13, 11),
                new PointF(21, 20),
                new PointF(3, 20),
                new PointF(11, 11),
                new PointF(5, 11),
                new PointF(11, 4),
                new PointF(8, 4)
            };

            PointF[] stump = new PointF[]
            {
                new PointF(10, 20),
                new PointF(14, 20),
                new PointF(14, 27),
                new PointF(19, 27),
                new PointF(19, 30),
                new PointF(6, 30),
                new PointF(6, 27),
                new PointF(10, 27)
            };

            using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                path.AddPolygon(tree);
                Matrix m = new Matrix();
                m.Scale(20, 20);
                path.Transform(m);
                e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Green, path);

                foreach (PointF p in path.PathPoints)
                {
                    int s = 15;
                    PointF q = p;
                    q.X -= (s / 2);
                    q.Y -= (s / 2);

                    if (new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()).Next(0, tree.Length) > tree.Length / 2)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, new RectangleF(q.X, q.Y, s, s));
                    }
                }
            }

            using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                path.AddPolygon(stump);
                Matrix m = new Matrix();
                m.Scale(20, 20);
                path.Transform(m);
                e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Brown, path);
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            Refresh();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the GraphicsPath.IsVisible function??